# Spring Data JPA PagingAndSortingRepository sorts encrypted data instead of decrypted data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, encryption

I'm storing encrypted data in my database using `AttributeConverter` and field level annotation ( eg. `@Convert(converter = StringEncrypt.class)`).
Everything is working fine, except that when I'm using `Pageable` with `PagindAndSortingRepository`, the sorting and paging is done on the encrypted data.

Any idea on how to solve this?

```
Pageable sortedBy = ListUtils.getPageable(pageAndSortType); // building a pageable
ArrayList<MyObject> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
myRepository.findAll(sortedBy).forEach(elementList::add); // querying the db with pageable object 
return elementList;
```

```
@Convert(converter = StringEncrypt.class)
private String name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, sorting is done on RDBMS side, so it will sort by content that is available to it. You will have either decrypt it on the fly in SQL or fetch all and sort it yourself. Your method call translates to some SQL `SELECT *.... sort by propertyName` and it is executed like that.

Every transformation you are doing, like eg by `@Convert` are done on application side AFTER data is fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any advices on how to do the sorting on the fly in SQL using the key?

Comment: You can use some implementation of decryption algorithm as database procedure, and use it it decrytp data before sorting - but that does not sound right.

Comment: So I should choose fetching and sorting by myself?

Comment: There are homomorphic encryption techniques that allow sorting, but you may not be able to apply those; it's not common that these are available out of the box and they are both complex and not all that performant.

Comment: How fast would be processing and sorting around 100k entities without cacheing?

Comment: Not fast. But in general sorting 100K records wont be fast.